# What is the performance context of Horace's Epode 1 and how can we explain the poet's handling of Time?

Tags: poetry, time, horatius

Was the performance context a symposium with Maecenas, the addressee present, and could the poem be re-purposed for another occasion?

Why does the poet use an incident in the Past and refer to it as if it is yet to come? Is this the influence of Greek Lyric, where the Past, Present and Future are seen as a continuum or is Horace simply comparing uncertainty in the Past with stability in the Present?

> Ibis Liburnis inter alta navium,
> amice, propugnacula,
> paratus omne Caesaris periculum
> subire, Maecenas, tuo:
> 5 quid nos, quibus te vita sit superstite
> iucunda, si contra, gravis?
> utrumne iussi persequemur otium
> non dulce, ni tecum simul,
> an hunc laborem mente laturi, decet
> 10 qua ferre non mollis viros?
> feremus et te vel per Alpium iuga
> inhospitalem et Caucasum
> vel occidentis usque ad ultimum sinum
> forti sequemur pectore.
> 15 roges, tuom labore quid iuvem meo,
> inbellis ac firmus parum?
> comes minore sum futurus in metu,
> qui maior absentis habet:
> ut adsidens inplumibus pullis avis
> 20 serpentium adlapsus timet
> magis relictis, non, ut adsit, auxili
> latura plus praesentibus.
> libenter hoc et omne militabitur
> bellum in tuae spem gratiae,
> 25 non ut iuvencis inligata pluribus
> aratra nitantur meis
> pecusve Calabris ante Sidus fervidum
> Lucana mutet pascuis
> neque ut superni villa candens Tusculi
> 30 Circaea tangat moenia:
> satis superque me benignitas tua
> ditavit, haud paravero
> quod aut avarus ut Chremes terra premam,
> discinctus aut perdam nepos.

Comment: Welcome to the site, interesting question! I have added the text, in order to make it easier for people to investigate. Could you perhaps explain a bit more about what you know about the epode? E.g. what is this incident? In what way does Greek lyric treat past, present, and future as a continuum? That can help readers, and possibly also enthuse respondents.

Comment: "Is this the influence of Greek Lyric, where the Past, Present and Future are seen as a continuum" I'll second Cerberus' questions. It seems as if statements like the above are provided in a learning context, perhaps a prompt by a professor, and therefore in a context that's specific to that class. If you can provide any more context, that would be immensely helpful, not only in providing a general answer to the main question, but to tailor it to the scholarship behind the way the body of the question is formulated.